# Linux app config location

Tags: linux, filesystems

Where is the appropriate place in the standard linux hierarchy to put config files for my apps?

Comment: [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#ETCHOSTSPECIFICSYSTEMCONFIGURATION) indicates either `/etc/` or `/etc/opt/<subdir>` may be appropriate given the nature of your application and/or distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system-wide config dir is `/etc`, but it is common to have relative `etc` dir within the standalone application. This depends on which one makes sense more for your case.

Comment: Is there a reason why he wouldn't put it in usr/local/bin? I just look as /etc as the directory that contains only config files for the system. I look at apps & their config files as something that would make more sense in /usr/local/bin since that's where software & other files are located for using on the local machine.

Comment: `bin` dir should contain binary files/scripts. It should work regardless of the directory you put your config files in. The point is just about organizing your files.

Answer (score 3):

Is your config system-wide? Files in `/etc` or your own subdirectory in there if you have a few of them.

Is your config per-user? The `$HOME/.your_file` or `$HOME/.your_directory/` if you have a few of them.

Comment: or $HOME/.config/

Answer (score 1):

What are "my apps"? Are these applications you develop, deploy, or test ?

In that case, your $HOME is completely free for you to use; existing applications often use `$HOME/.appname/` as a config and/or storage directory.

For system-wide installed apps, the standard is `/usr/local/etc/appname` if you installed the app in /usr/local/*.